# Redux: actions triggered twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a `NavigationIcons` component that has few navigation icons, including `Add Item` icon. When clicking Add Item, a modal shows up on the screen. The modal has a close button, so when close button is clicked, I want the modal to disappear from screen.
Problem is that when I click to open the modal from navigation buttons, it triggers `OPEN_ADD_ITEM_MODAL` and modal is displayed, when I try to close it, it triggers both `CLOSE_ADD_ITEM_MODAL` and `OPEN_ADD_ITEM_MODAL`. I do not understand why it triggers `OPEN_ADD_ITEM_MODAL` since it is used only in `onClick={() => props.openAddItemModal()}` event for NavigationIcons Add Item icon.

Could someone please explain what is wrong here? I added `props.addItem` as dependency for `useEffect` in NavigationIcons to rerender when store changes but still I have no clue. The `console.log` from NavigationIcons always displays `true`.

NavigationIcons compnent

```
const NavigationIcons = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedHeaderNavigationIcon(props.headerNavigationIcon);
    console.log(props.addItem);
  }, [props.headerNavigationIcon, selectedHeaderNavigationIcon, props.addItem]);

  return (
    .....
      <div className="add-item-icon" onClick={() => props.openAddItemModal()}>
        {console.log(props.addItem)}
        {props.addItem && <AddItemModal />}

        <div className="main"></div>
      </div>
   .....
  );
  const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    addItem: state.addItem.open,
  });
  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    openAddItemModal: () => dispatch(openAddItemModal()),
  });
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavigationIcons);
}
```

AddItemModal Component

```
const AddItemModal = (props) => {

 const handleModalClose = () => {
    props.closeAddItemModal();
 };
 return ReactDOM.createPortal(
   <div className="modal">
     <ModalHeader handleModalClose={handleModalClose} />
     ...A lot of JSX
 )
  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    closeAddItemModal: () => dispatch(closeAddItemModal()),
  });
  export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddItemModal);
}
```

ModalHeader component

```
const ModalHeader = (props) => (
  <div className="main">
    Add item
    <div className="close" onClick={() => props.handleModalClose()}>
      close
    </div>
  <div>
)
```

Redux actions

```
export const openAddItemModal = () => ({
  type: AddItemActionTypes.OPEN_ADD_ITEM_MODAL,
});

export const closeAddItemModal = () => ({
  type: AddItemActionTypes.CLOSE_ADD_ITEM_MODAL,
});
```

Redux reducer (I had just 1 case, for toggling, open: !state.open, but since I saw that state did change for closing the modal, decided to have explicitly open/close)

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  open: false,
};

const addItemReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AddItemActionTypes.OPEN_ADD_ITEM_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        open: true,
      };

    case AddItemActionTypes.CLOSE_ADD_ITEM_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        open: false,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I use redux-logger, this is how I can see what actions are triggered.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your AddItemModal is nested inside the div that opens it, the event bubbles up to the father and trigger its onClick.

Add `event.stopPropagation` to the handleModalClose function:

```
const handleModalClose = evt => {

   evt.stopPropagation();
   props.closeAddModal()

}
```

Or just create the AddItemModal as a sibling, instead of a child of said div.